# Resources for historical performance BEYOND 10 years?

Tags: united-states, stocks, historical-analysis

I have looked around MorningStar and Yahoo, but I cannot find an online resource that provides historical stick and mutual fund performance beyond 10 years.  Does anyone have a link or suggestion for seeing this?

Comment: Click on "Max" the IBM chart goes back to 1961.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on finance.yahoo.com you can click on historical prices.  You would have to download it to a spreadsheet and then you can work on it with whatever tools you have.